# Circuit Breakers with NestJs

Tags: microservices, nestjs, circuit-breaker

planing to develop a application with micro services using NestJS. i want to know how to apply   Circuit Breakers to the NestJS application. can someone give me a hint/support/ any sample code or whatever resource which helpful for me

Answer (score 2):

Circuit breaking is a pattern that applies to service-to-service requests and doesn't have a whole lot to do with NestJS in particular. If you plan on instrumenting several NestJS APIs that communicate with one another, I'd suggest you look to configure circuit breakers inside the load balancers or service mesh. Here's a few links that can help you explore how do to that with Nginx, Hashicorp Consul, and AWS AppMesh respectively:

- https://www.nginx.com/blog/microservices-reference-architecture-nginx-circuit-breaker-pattern/
- https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/consul/service-mesh-circuit-breaking?in=consul/developer-mesh
- https://github.com/aws/aws-app-mesh-roadmap/issues/6#issuecomment-694598440

Answer (score 0):

We did this for a project a few years ago where we wrapped circuit breakers with a Decorator used on Nest. https://github.com/valor-software/nest-circuit-breaker

This allowed us to use patterns like this

```js
@CircuitBreakerProtected({
 circuitBreakerSleepWindowInMilliseconds: 3000,
 circuitBreakerErrorThresholdPercentage: 50,
 circuitBreakerRequestVolumeThreshold: 10,
 timeout: 10000,
 statisticalWindowLength: 10000,
 statisticalWindowNumberOfBuckets: 10,
 percentileWindowLength: 10000,
 percentileWindowNumberOfBuckets: 10,
 requestVolumeRejectionThreshold: 0,
 fallbackTo: undefined,
 shouldErrorBeConsidered: undefined
})
```